# Is there a way to extends a base module when I use thor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

I want to make a batch under a rails project.

I have created a base batch module:

```
# lib/tasks/batch_base.rb
module Tasks
  class BatchBase
    def run
      # Run something
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to make a batch with [thor](http://whatisthor.com/).

```
# lib/tasks/another_batch.rb
require 'thor'
module Tasks
  class AnotherBatch < Thor
    desc 'test', 'sample'
    def hello(name)
      # Do something
    end
  end
end
```

Here I want to extends the base batch, but when I try:

```
class AnotherBatch < BatchBase < Thor
# or
class AnotherBatch < Thor < BatchBase
```

It doesn't work. Error:

```
superclass must be a Class (NilClass given) (TypeError)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your concerns correctly you should declare your `BatchBase` as a module and you'll have something like that

```
 
module Tasks
  module BatchBase
    def run
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

require 'thor'
module Tasks
  class AnotherBatch < Thor
    include BatchBase
  end
end

Ruby does not have multiple inheritance, you should use mixins instead.
You can read more about it [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#UA)